# stella sdk error in Xcode 4.6.2

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I developed an app with Xcode 4. I want to convert it to android using Stella SDK. Can anyone tell me what is wrong and how to fix it? I followed the [PDF guide given on their website][1] "width Stella SDK getting started" but I don't know where I'm wrong ...

```
CompileC build-arm-google-android/noraetxera-android.build/Debug/noraetxera.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o noraPro/main.m normal i386 objective-c com.yeecco.compilers.android.clang.1.0
    cd /Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /opt/StellaSDK/bin/android-clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/build-arm-google-android/Debug/include -I/opt/StellaSDK/arm-google-android/usr/include -I/opt/StellaSDK/arm-google-android/System/Library/Frameworks/cocos2d.framework/Headers -I/opt/StellaSDK/arm-google-android/System/Library/Frameworks/StellaMedia.framework/Headers -I/opt/StellaSDK/arm-google-android/System/Library/Frameworks/StellaStore.framework/Headers -I/Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/build-arm-google-android/noraetxera-android.build/Debug/noraetxera.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/build-arm-google-android/noraetxera-android.build/Debug/noraetxera.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/build-arm-google-android/Debug -F/opt/StellaSDK/arm-google-android/System/Library/Frameworks -stella_target arm-google-android -D__STELLA_NANDROID -D__STELLA_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/build-arm-google-android/noraetxera-android.build/Debug/noraetxera.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.d -c /Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/noraPro/main.m -o /Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/build-arm-google-android/noraetxera-android.build/Debug/noraetxera.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o

clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fobjc-arc'
warning: unknown warning option '-Wreceiver-is-weak' [-Wunknown-warning-option]
warning: unknown warning option '-Wduplicate-method-match' [-Wunknown-warning-option]
warning: unknown warning option '-Wint-conversion' [-Wunknown-warning-option]
warning: unknown warning option '-Wenum-conversion' [-Wunknown-warning-option]
In file included from /Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/noraPro/main.m:11:
/Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/noraPro/AppDelegate.h:17:12: error: unknown property attribute 'strong'
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
           ^
/Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/noraPro/AppDelegate.h:17:1: warning: no 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
^
/Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/noraPro/AppDelegate.h:17:1: warning: default property attribute 'assign' not appropriate for non-gc object
/Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/noraPro/AppDelegate.h:20:12: error: unknown property attribute 'strong'
@property (strong, nonatomic) paso1480 *view480;
           ^
/Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/noraPro/AppDelegate.h:20:1: warning: no 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed
@property (strong, nonatomic) paso1480 *view480;
^
/Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/noraPro/AppDelegate.h:20:1: warning: default property attribute 'assign' not appropriate for non-gc object
/Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/noraPro/AppDelegate.h:21:12: error: unknown property attribute 'strong'
@property (strong, nonatomic) paso1568 *view568;
           ^
/Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/noraPro/AppDelegate.h:21:1: warning: no 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed
@property (strong, nonatomic) paso1568 *view568;
^
/Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/noraPro/AppDelegate.h:21:1: warning: default property attribute 'assign' not appropriate for non-gc object
/Users/umarzo/Documents/bortxnoraPro/noraPro/main.m:15:5: error: unexpected '@' in program
    @autoreleasepool {
    ^
10 warnings and 4 errors generated.
Command /opt/StellaSDK/bin/android-clang failed with exit code 1
```